# Understanding why the projection map of the cartesian product of metric space is a continuous map

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I am trying to understand this paragraph:
[image]

I am not sure why this implies that the projection map is continuous. There is another proof by showing that the preimage of open sets is open and that one is more understandable.

Comment: Which definition(s) of continuity are you familiar with?

Comment: In my understanding, the projection $\Pi_X(x_n,y_n) = x_n$ and $\Pi_X(x,y) = x$. Therefore $x_n \to x\implies \Pi_X(x_n,y_n)\to\Pi_X(x,y) $. Similarly for $\Pi_Y$. therefore the $\textit{projections}$ are continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as far as I understand, you are considering the product $X\times Y$ of two metric spaces $X$ and $Y$.

Such product enjoy natural metrics such as $d((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))=\max(d_X(x_1,x_2),d_Y(y_1,y_2))$ where  $d_X$ and $d_Y$ are the metrics of $X$ and $Y$ (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_metric). This makes $X\times Y$ a metric space.

Metric spaces have a nice property: for applications between metric spaces, sequential continuity is equivalent to continuity.

Informally speaking, sequential continuity is the property of an application $f$ to satisfy $\lim_{n}f(x_n)=f(x)$ for any sequence $(x_n)_n$ converging to $x$.

What it tells you, in particular, is that the projection $\Pi_X:X\times Y\mapsto X$ is continuous if and only if [for any $(x,y)$ and any sequence $(x_n,y_n)_{n\geq 1}$ converging to $(x,y)$,  $\Pi_X(x_n,y_n)$ converges to $\Pi_X(x,y)$].